# Free falling bodies in the absence of external forces

Tags: classical-mechanics, gravity, newtonian-gravity, solid-state-physics, free-fall

We know that if two balls $B_{1}$ and $B_{2}$ having masses $m_{1}$ and $m_{2}$ respectively and suppose $m_{1}$ is sufficient greater than $m_{2}$. In daily life observation, we see that  both the balls reached to earth at the same time. I'm confuse that why the reach both at the same time because $W$ (weight=force at which earth attracts bodies) depend on mass as $W=mg$. So why the ball of $m_{1}$ does not reach to ground first as compared ball with mass $m_{2}$?

Comment: In everyday observation, you would notice that the heavier ball falls first. Both balls fall together in the absence of air resistance, which is an idealisation.

Comment: why they reach at same time? because weight mathematically depend on the value of $m$.

Comment: The weight depends on the mass $m$, but their acceleration which is $W / m = g$, is independent of $m$. This is why they reach the ground in the same time when dropped from the same height.

Comment: $g=W/m$ so clearly $g$ depends on mass.

Comment: The value of $g$ is $9.80 m/s^2$ near the earth's surface. It's a constant.

Answer (score 2):

$\vec F = m\vec a$ where $\vec F $ is the applied force, $m$ the mass, and $\vec a$ the acceleration.  For gravity close to the earth $\vec F = m\vec g$ where $\vec g$ is constant.  So $m\vec g = m\vec a$ and thus $\vec a \ = \vec g$.  The acceleration of a mass $m$ is the same, $\vec g$, regardless of the mass. For a constant acceleration $\vec a$ downward, the time to fall a distance $y$ is $y = {1 \over 2} at^2$ and for gravity $a= g$, the time to fall $y$ is $\sqrt{{2x \over g}}$ independent of the mass $m$.

Answer (score 0):

Newton’s second law applied to each of the two masses yield the same acceleration $g$, them acceleration of free fall because even though the larger mass has the gravitational attractive force on it that gravitational force has to accelerate a larger mass.

$F=ma \Rightarrow m_1 g = m_1 a_1 \Rightarrow g=a_1$ and $m_2 g = m_2 a_2 \Rightarrow g=a_2$, so $a_1=a_2=g$.

Answer (score 0):

If the balls were dropped in a vacuum, both balls would experience the same acceleration, which if near the surface of the earth would be $g$. From Newton's 2nd law $a=F/m$. Since the force of gravity $F_g$ is $mg$ (the weight) for all bodies, then $a=mg/m=g$, but only in a vacuum.

That's because if objects fall in a fluid, such as air, they will experience an upward drag force $F_D$ given by (see NASA reference below)

$$F_{D}=\frac{1}{2}\rho v^{2}C_{D}A$$

Where

$\rho$ = density of fluid (air)

$v$ = speed of object relative to the fluid

$C_{D}$= drag coefficient (experimentally determined)

$A$ = cross sectional area in direction of motion

Note that the drag force for a given fluid does not depend on the mass, but rather on the physical dimensions and surface characteristics of the object and the experimentally determined drag coefficient.

Consequently the acceleration of each ball will depend on the net downward force on each, or the downward force of gravity minus the upward air drag force, or, for each body

$$F_{net}=mg-F_{D}$$

The acceleration of each body will equal the net force acting on it divided by its mass. Or for each mass

$$a_{m_1}=\frac{F_{net}}{m_1}=g-\frac{F_{D1}}{m_1}\tag{1}$$

$$a_{m_2}=\frac{F_{net}}{m_2}=g-\frac{F_{D2}}{m_2}\tag{2}$$

From equations (1) and (2) one can see that the ball having the lower ratio of drag force to mass will undergo the greater downward acceleration and reach the earth first.

Finally, regarding "daily life observation", it depends on what you are observing. If the balls are dropped close to the ground so that their speed at impact is very low, you may not see a difference, because the drag force varies as the square of the speed. The greater the dropping height, the more noticeable the difference, all other things being equal.

Hope this helps.

[https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/drageq.html#:~:text=The%20drag%20equation%20states%20that,times%20the%20reference%20area%20A.&text=For%20given%20air%20conditions%2C%20shape,for%20Cd%20to%20determine%20drag](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/drageq.html#:%7E:text=The%20drag%20equation%20states%20that,times%20the%20reference%20area%20A.&text=For%20given%20air%20conditions%2C%20shape,for%20Cd%20to%20determine%20drag).

Answer (score 0):

Neglecting any kind of resistance, and assuming the height from which balls are released is not very large (the height must be very small as compared to the radius of earth), THEN the answer is simple!

"Since acceleration is constant".

Motion of objects depends on its acceleration, since the objects started from the same point and they accelerate equally every time, they will indeed go together in the whole part of their journey.

But getting into your question, which points on practical observations, includes obviously resistance of the medium. In that case, things are very different. Heavy objects will feel less resistance as compared to lighter ones (think of bouyant force) and so suffers lesser retarding acceleration which implies bigger net acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that gravity pulls harder in the heavy object.

You are forgetting that the heavy object is also harder to move.

These two effects happen to perfectly balance each other out. An object with double the mass feels double the gravitational force *but also* requires double as much force to accelerate to the same degree - thus the end-result is the exact same motion. As others have already pointed out, this can mathematically be shown via Newton's 2nd law:

$$\text{Object } B_1:\quad\sum F=m_1a_1\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad w_1=m_1a_1\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad m_1g=m_1a_1\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad g=a_1$$
$$\text{Object }B_2:\quad\sum F=m_2a_2\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad w_2=m_2a_2\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad m_2g=m_2a_2\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad g=a_2$$

Any influence of the involved masses cancels out regardless of their size, and both objects end up falling with the gravitational acceleration $g$.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way. Mass number one is made of 100 Hydrogen atoms and mass number two is made of 1 hydrogen atom. if you divide mass number one into 100 separate pieces and dropped them all together they would each fall at the same speed as mass number two. Gravity is acting on each of the fundamental particles separately.